# how to rename a large amount of similar named file names in a single directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a single Linux directory with a lot of files named like this:

```
page_something1.php
page_somethingelse.php
page_anotherthing.php
page_yet_another_file_name.php
etc.
```

I'd like to change the filenames of these to:

```
newname_something1.php
newname_somethingelse.php
newname_anotherthing.php
newname_yet_another_file_name.php
etc.
```

So basically, just change the "page_" part to "newname_" of all the files in this directory.

Is there any easy command I can run to rename them all at once rather than spending 3 hours changing them one by one with

```
mv page_something1.php newname_something1.php
```

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: You should search this site for `rename`. This is dedicated for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer, yay!

```
for file in page*
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/page/newname}"
done
```